# What is better repository design?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, repository

I have tables that I insert, delete and update, but I read from views.  At times, I may read from the tables as well.  What is a better generic interface for a Repository:

```
public interface IViewRepository<T>
{
  //Read queries
}

public interface ITableRepository<T>
{
  //Insert, Update, Delete queries
}
```

or just one repository to handle both tables and views

```
public interface IRepository<TTable,TView>
{
  //CRUD
}
```

Is it better to have something like `IPersonRepository` and `ICarRepository` and then in the interfaces, make the methods generic such as `T GetPerson<T>` and `T GetCar<T>`?

Comment: Your crud shouldn't know the difference between a table and a view.  That's an implementation detail that it should know nothing about.  So neither interface is satisfactory.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The problem I am facing is that I have one set of POCO objects that map to tables and others that map to views. In general my POCO classes are different. Are you suggesting that I just have an IRepository<T> or just avoid generics in this case. If I use generics, it would make no sense to do insert/updates/deletes on views? Should I just have an interface for each POCO type such as IPersonRepository?

Comment: Complete opinion here, but I've always ended up frustrated with the inflexibility of generic repositories, especially those with abstract base classes. I'd say skip the whole IRepository<Person> concept altogether and go with IPersonRepository. You can do whatever you want inside your repository, and your consuming code doesn't need to know if it's a table, or a view, or a file on disk, or a web service, or whatever.

Comment: @EricKing - I was messing around with some different options and feel I may go that route.  I think I will just go with something like you mentioned and just use the POCO necessary to do the job (return a PersonView when doing a GetAll and Inserting a Person when doing an Insert).

Comment: `IRepository<TTable,TView>` What would an example of the generic types be here? Is it something like `TCarTable` and `TCarView`? Do they have different public members or the same?

Comment: @BenAaronson - They are different.  There are basically 2 tables (a header and a detail) and the view is combination of both.

Answer (score 1):

I think the question needs to be split into two parts. Firstly, what is the role of the POCOs representing your database objects, and secondly, how best to structure repositories to deal with them.

---

In answer to the first question, you seem to have chosen to map your POCOs directly to database objects- one class exactly represents on table, or one view. But there's another option too, which is to have a class represent an *entity*- the conceptual object that your data describes. For example, instead of a `CarView`, `CarHeaderTable` and `CarVersionTable` (or whatever naming scheme you use), your POCO would just be a `Car`.

The main pros and cons of these two options as I see them:

**Pro-Direct mapping**

- It's very simple! There's no need to deal with any complexities in mapping database objects to POCOs.
- It still provides many of the benefits of an ORM (or a hand-rolled solution involving mapping database objects to POCOs). You still remove repetitive code involving pulling data into and out of `DataTable`s, you still isolate your non data-access code from having to worry about SQL, and so on.

**Pro-Conceptual POCOs**

- Rather than just shield your code from *SQL* concerns, you get to shield it from *persistence* concerns altogether (at least as far as your class design goes). Now any code that just wants to deal with a `Car` can deal with a `Car`, without having to worry itself about whether this is a `Car` that's designed to be read or a `Car` that's designed to be written to, and whether it's just the immutable bits of a `Car` or just the mutable bits, or both. As your design stands, it doesn't really do anything to address impedance mismatch (Robert C. Martin talks about this [here](http://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2013/10/01/Dance-You-Imps.html))
- You cut down on the number of classes which are really just there to provide the same information in different ways. I don't know what you do currently when you want to add a method (perhaps a simple calculation) to one of these POCOs. Is that banned? Do you duplicate it across all classes representing the same thing? Do you create a `CarHelper` that does things the `Car` should really be able to do itself? With a single `Car` class that's no longer a problem.

---

If you pick the second of the above two options, this question pretty much goes away. But maybe you've already considered the above, or you do so now and decide that on balance you one to stick with the direct POCO-to-DB object mapping. In that case, you're still left with the question of which option is best.

To start with, as Robert Harvey said, you probably don't want `Table` and `View` in your terminology, as it's very specific to databases. `Readable` and `Writeable` might be better terminology, for both versions.

Beyond that, I think the best option is the one that suits the consumers of these repositories. Does code which reads usually also want to write, and vice-versa? Then packaging them together, as in the second version, is probably a good idea.

As Eric King alluded to in the comments, starting with a base repository is actually a somewhat backwards way of approaching this- you're starting by creating an inheritance structure designed to deal with common/repeated concerns, without actually having any repeated concerns to deal with!

So my advice would be- create an `ICarRepository` and add to it as is needed by its consuming code. Do the same thing with `IPersonRepository`. As these classes grow, you can refactor- do you find that putting the table-related members together with the view-related ones feels like a violation of the ISP (Interface Segregation Principle)? Then split them up. Is there repeated, generic-feeling functionality? Then extract a base `Repository<T>` (or `Repository<TWriteable,TReadable>`) class. That way instead of doing design based on guesswork, you'll be creating a design driven by how it's used.